# Why is the python index function execution time faster than my own linear search function?

Tags: python

I'm doing an experiment comparing the execution time of the index function and my own linear search function. To my understanding, Python implements a linear search algorithm for the index function so the execution time should be roughly the same, shouldn't it?

My own search function looks like this

```
def linearSearch (x,numList,length):      
    n = 0
    for i in range(length):
            n = n + 1
            if numList[i] == x:
                    return i, n
    return -1, n
```

Comment: No. Your search is using Python, Python's is using compiled-C code (if you are using CPython). The time *complexity* will be the same, though.

Comment: Ah thanks for the response. So the two functions are not directly comparable because they use different languages?

Comment: Python probably doesn't use a Python implementation for `index`; it probably uses some C code (or the native language of the implementation for Jython, etc).

Comment: Roughly, yes. Although, if you are using PyPy, `index` will be written in Python!

Comment: You could put `time.sleep(1000)` inside your for-loop and its algorithmic complexity would still be O(N).

Answer (score 5):

This is a very important thing to understand... **`O(N)` tells you *nothing* about how quickly the operation will complete.**  Just because your implementation and python's implementation are both `O(N)`, that doesn't mean that they'll both take the same amount of time.

What `O(N)` tells you is that if one implementation takes 1s to process 100 items, it'll probably take about 2s to process 200 items.  In other words, `O(N)` tells you how the time spent in the algorithm will *scale* as the size of the input changes.

---

In this case, python's search will always beat your search because python's search is operating in `C` (assuming CPython) with very little overhead for the interpreter -- whereas your implementation has to do a lot of lookups in "python-space" (which is surprisingly expensive in comparison).

Some python implementations with a good JIT (e.g. `pypy`) will be able to reduce this difference, but I doubt that you'll ever be able to beat the performance of the optimized built-in function.

Answer (score 4):

Python's `list.index` function runs at C speed, and I don't see how your Python variant can possibly beat that.

This of course assumes your Python installation uses CPython.

Answer (score 1):

Python was written in C which happens to be around 5 times faster than python. This means that your code which is written in Python is approximately 5 times slower than the index() method written in C.